# why i can not obtain iframe.contentWindow after iframe onload?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEP3M.png)

I want to switch my iframe's URL, but I can not obtain iframe.contentWindow after iframe onload

Comment: it is better to post code rather than image snippet.

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as your main window? I smell [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problems around here